# selfjoin on subquery on then same table performance

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a table T (~120 million rows):

```
ID  CAT GRP SUB SEQ CO  Score
1   04S 72  200 60  047 0
1   04S 72  200 65  047 7
1   04S 72  200 69  050 0
1   04S 72  200 70  050 1
1   04S 72  200 71  050 2
1   04S 72  200 72  050 0
1   04S 72  200 83  053 9
1   04S 72  200 84  053 7
1   04S 72  200 85  053 9
1   04S 72  200 86  053 1
```

I need to select those records where `Score` is maximum for grouping on `ID, CAT, GRP, SUB, CO`.
So in this case the outcome would be (the data in brackets should not be shown after the select):

```
ID  CAT GRP SUB SEQ (CO Score)
1   04S 72  200 65  (047    7)
1   04S 72  200 71  (050    2)
1   04S 72  200 83  (053    9)
1   04S 72  200 85  (053    9)
```

This is my query but it takes multiple hours to complete:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        T.ID,
        T.CAT,
        T.GRP,
        T.SUB,
        T.SEQ
FROM T
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                   ID,
                   CAT,
                   GRP,
                   SUB,
                   CO,
                   MAX(Score) AS Score
            FROM T
            GROUP BY ID,CAT,GRP,SUB,CO,POS
           ) AS T1
    ON T.ID = T1.ID AND T.CAT = T1.CAT AND T.GRP = T1.GRP AND T.SUB = T1.SUB AND T.CO = T1.CO AND T.Score = T1.Score;
```

Is there a better way to write the query performance-wise?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ID,CAT,GRP,SUB,SEQ,CO,Score
FROM data_table
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, CAT, GRP, SUB, CO ORDER BY Score DESC)
```